# Search All Files and Folders On Phone?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to search all files and folders for documents that are on a phone or tablet. Seems like I can only search certain directories, but want to search for all files for pdfs and docx documents. Something like:

```
getLocal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.localFileButton);
    getLocal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findFiles(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
        }
    });
}

private void findFiles(File dir){
    //We could put these in an enumeration
    String pdfPattern = ".pdf";
    String docPattern = ".docx";
    String txtPattern = ".txt";

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null){
        for (int i = 0; i <= listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(txtPattern)){
                    //Do what ever u want

                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No files on the phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

I don't want to limit the search to just one folder, I want to search for any available folders, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since the scan-the-filesystem approach that you are using is going away with Android 10+, you might want to rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: For Android Q you can use Storage Access Framework to scan primary partition and micro SD card.

Comment: Storage Access Framework looks promising, going to have to play with it and see what it does.